# React Navigation Bottom TabBar Icon Spacing

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am using React Navigation with React Native. This is on Android.

1. I am trying to add some spacing between the icon and the top of the tab bar and reduce the spacing between icon and the label.
2. I am trying to change the bottom border color ie Yellow line.
3. I am trying to reduce the spacing, padding left and right inside each cell.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

```
{
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    animationEnabled: true,
    swipeEnabled: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
      showIcon: true,
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 8
      },
      style: {
        backgroundColor: 'grey',
      },
      tabStyle: {
        height: 49
      },
      iconStyle: {
        flexGrow: 0,
        marginTop: 1.5
      }
    }
  }
```

[image: BottomTabBar]

Comment: Its really hard to help out. Can you put it in a snack? snack.expo.com

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Regarding the first problem about the *spacing between the icon and the top of the tab bar* you can add padding to the `tabStyle` property in `tabBarOptions`:

```
tabBarOptions: {
    tabStyle: {
        paddingVertical: 5
    }
}
```

For *reducing the space between the icon and the label*, you can add some padding or margin to your `Icon` object:

```
tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => {
    return <Icon containerStyle={{ marginTop: 6 }} name="map" size={25} color={tintColor} />;
},
```

About the problem with the *active Yellow line* on Android, you can change the background color property to be `transparent` or set `0` for height:

```
tabBarOptions: {
    indicatorStyle: {
        height: 0
    }
}
```

And for the last problem about the problem about the *space between the cells*, I don't think that there is a solution for now.

You can try to make the navigation smaller ( for example: `width: '80%'` )... this will set the cells closer to each other... but I have never tried that and I am not sure is it a good solution ;)

Comment: you should use ```renderIndicator: () => null,``` to not display the highlight on the bottom.

Comment: paddingVertical does not seem to change the distance between the icon and the top bar.

Answer (score 2):

To change the distance between the icon and the top of the bar (Question **1** as of **react-navigation 4.x**), add padding to ***tabStyle*** inside ***tabBarOptions***:

```
tabBarOptions: {
    tabStyle: {
      paddingBottom: 8,
      paddingTop: 8,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the indicatorStyle config option:

```
tabBarOptions: {

    indicatorStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <Tab.Screen
    name="Account"
    component={Account}
    options={{
      tabBarItemStyle: {paddingTop: 5},//use This for Icon or image
      tabBarLabelStyle: {paddingBottom: 5},// use This for lable 
      tabBarLabel: 'Account',
      tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
        <UserIcon
          width={SIZES.huge_20}
          height={SIZES.huge_20}
          fill={color}
        />
```